# Redux reducer boolean value won't work react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to check the user's answer to a questions and update the "global" answer state true or false accordingly. These are the actions I use:

```
export const answerTrue = () => {
  return { type: `ANSWER_TRUE` };
};
```

and if the answer is wrong:

```
export const answerFalse = () => {
  return { type: `ANSWER_FALSE` };
};
```

Here is my reducer:

```
function answerReducer(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case `ANSWER_TRUE`:
      return (state = true);
      break;
    case `ANSWER_FALSE`:
      return (state = false);
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default answerReducer;
```

This is my handler to change the state:

```
  const answerHandler = () => {
    if (userInput === props.finalAnswer) {
      dispatch(answerTrue());
    } else {
      dispatch(answerFalse())
    }
  };
```

When I console.log it will automatocall run "true, false, true". It basically never stops at "false".

I use my handler via checkedHandler like so:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_1();
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={
            (box_1_Visibility === true && styles.mainContainer) || styles.hide
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked_1 == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked_1 == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.box_1_Label}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

And this is the checkedHandler:

```
  const checkedHandler_6 = () => {
    if (checked_6 == false) {
      setChecked_6(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_6_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_6(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_6_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };
```

Finally: This is the checkbox component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { answerTrue } from "../store/actions/answerTrue";
import { answerFalse } from "../store/actions/answerFalse";



function AnswerContainer_CheckBox(props) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const makeAnswerStateFalseAgainHandler = () => {
    dispatch(answerFalse());
  };


  const [checked_1, setChecked_1] = useState(false);
  const [checked_2, setChecked_2] = useState(false);
  const [checked_3, setChecked_3] = useState(false);
  const [checked_4, setChecked_4] = useState(false);
  const [checked_5, setChecked_5] = useState(false);
  const [checked_6, setChecked_6] = useState(false);

  const [box_1_Visibility, setBox_1_Visibility] = useState(
    props.box_1_Visibility
  );
  const [box_2_Visibility, setBox_2_Visibility] = useState(
    props.box_2_Visibility
  );
  const [box_3_Visibility, setBox_3_Visibility] = useState(
    props.box_3_Visibility
  );
  const [box_4_Visibility, setBox_4_Visibility] = useState(
    props.box_4_Visibility
  );
  const [box_5_Visibility, setBox_5_Visibility] = useState(
    props.box_5_Visibility
  );
  const [box_6_Visibility, setBox_6_Visibility] = useState(
    props.box_6_Visibility
  );

  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

  const answerHandler = () => {
    if (userInput === props.finalAnswer) {
      dispatch(answerTrue());
    } else {
      dispatch(answerFalse())
    }
  };


  const checkedHandler_1 = () => {
    if (checked_1 == false) {
      setChecked_1(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_1_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_1(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_1_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };
  const checkedHandler_2 = () => {
    if (checked_2 == false) {
      setChecked_2(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_2_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_2(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_2_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };
  const checkedHandler_3 = () => {
    if (checked_3 == false) {
      setChecked_3(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_3_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_3(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_3_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };
  const checkedHandler_4 = () => {
    if (checked_4 == false) {
      setChecked_4(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_4_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_4(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_4_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };
  const checkedHandler_5 = () => {
    if (checked_5 == false) {
      setChecked_5(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_5_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_5(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_5_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };
  const checkedHandler_6 = () => {
    if (checked_6 == false) {
      setChecked_6(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_6_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_6(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_6_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Checkbox 1 */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_1();
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={
            (box_1_Visibility === true && styles.mainContainer) || styles.hide
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked_1 == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked_1 == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.box_1_Label}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* Checkbox 2 */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_2();
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={
            (box_2_Visibility === true && styles.mainContainer) || styles.hide
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked_2 == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked_2 == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.box_2_Label}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* Checkbox 3 */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_3();
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={
            (box_3_Visibility === true && styles.mainContainer) || styles.hide
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked_3 == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked_3 == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.box_3_Label}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* Checkbox 4 */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_4();
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={
            (box_4_Visibility === true && styles.mainContainer) || styles.hide
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked_4 == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked_4 == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.box_4_Label}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* Checkbox 5 */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_5();
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={
            (box_5_Visibility === true && styles.mainContainer) || styles.hide
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked_5 == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked_5 == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.box_5_Label}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* Checkbox 6 */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_6();
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={
            (box_6_Visibility === true && styles.mainContainer) || styles.hide
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked_6 == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked_6 == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.box_6_Label}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}


export default AnswerContainer_CheckBox;
```

And this is the screen I am using it in:

```
// Imports
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import AnswerContainer_CheckBox from "../../../components/AnswerContainer_CheckBox";
import { BottomPopUp } from "../../../components/BottonPopUp";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { answerFalse } from "../../../store/actions/answerFalse";
import { reduceExperiencePoints } from "../../../store/actions/reduceExperiencePoints";
import { addExperiencePoints } from "../../../store/actions/addExperiencePoints";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

function Einfuehrung_3_noTab(props) {

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [modalFalseVisible, setModalFalseVisible] = useState(false);

  const highlightText = (string) =>
    string.split(" ").map((word, i) => (
      <Text key={i}>
        <Text style={styles.highlightText}>{word} </Text>
      </Text>
    ));


  const UserAnswer = useSelector((state) => state.answerReducerKey);


  /* Set global Answer State*/
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const makeAnswerStateFalseAgainHandler = () => {
    dispatch(answerFalse());
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    makeAnswerStateFalseAgainHandler();
  }, []);


  // Get Experience Points
  const ExperiencePoints = useSelector(
    (state) => state.experiencePointsReducerKey
  );
  const GlobalExperiencePoints = useSelector(
    (state) => state.experiencePointsWalletReducerKey
  );

  // Add and reduce Experince Points
  const addExperiencePointsHandler = () => {
    dispatch(addExperiencePoints());
  };
  const reduceExperiencePointsHandler = () => {
    dispatch(reduceExperiencePoints());
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.background}>
        <View style={styles.textColumn}>
          <Image
            style={styles.backBtn}
            source={require("../../../assets/class/xback.png")}
          />
          <Text style={styles.mainText}>
            {ExperiencePoints} Welche dieser Städte liegen
            {GlobalExperiencePoints} nicht in Europa?
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.divider}></View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.answerContainer}>
          <AnswerContainer_CheckBox
            finalAnswer={"AC"}
            box_1_Visibility={true}
            box_2_Visibility={true}
            box_3_Visibility={true}
            box_4_Visibility={true}
            box_5_Visibility={false}
            box_6_Visibility={false}
            box_1_Label={"Shanghai"}
            box_1_Letter={"A"}
            box_2_Label={"Paris"}
            box_2_Letter={"B"}
            box_3_Label={"New York"}
            box_3_Letter={"C"}
            box_4_Label={"Berlin"}
            box_4_Letter={"D"}
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.submitBt}
          onPress={() => {
            if (UserAnswer === true) {
              addExperiencePointsHandler();
              setModalVisible(true);
            } else {
              reduceExperiencePointsHandler();
              setModalFalseVisible(true);
            }
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Antwort prüfen</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {/*Correct Answer Modal*/}
      <BottomPopUp visible={modalVisible}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "44%",
            marginTop: "auto",
            borderColor: "#ccc",
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderStyle: "solid",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            elevation: 20,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 4,
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.modalTextContainer}>
            <View style={styles.modalFirstLineContainer}>
              <Image
                style={styles.gifAnimation}
                source={require("../../../assets/class/clapping_hands.gif")}
              />
              <Text style={styles.modalHeader}>Die Antwort ist korrekt!</Text>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.mainText}>
              Dummy Text
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.nextBt}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(false);
                makeAnswerStateFalseAgainHandler(); 
                props.navigation.navigate("Einfuehrung_4_noTab");
              }}
            >
              <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>weiter</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </BottomPopUp>

      {/*Wrong Answer Modal*/}
      <BottomPopUp visible={modalFalseVisible}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "44%",
            marginTop: "auto",
            borderColor: "#ccc",
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderStyle: "solid",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            elevation: 20,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 4,
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.modalTextContainer}>
            <View style={styles.modalFirstLineContainer}>
              <Image
                style={styles.gifAnimation}
                source={require("../../../assets/class/thinking_face.gif")}
              />
              <Text style={styles.modalHeader}>Die Antwort ist falsch!!</Text>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.mainText}>Was ist los mit Dir?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.closeBt}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalFalseVisible(false);
              }}
            >
              <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>
                  <FontAwesome name="close" size={24} color="white" />
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </BottomPopUp>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default Einfuehrung_3_noTab;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you using your handler ? sorry that might be the issue as it seems to be toggling it

in your switch statement you also dont need to have the break statement aswell as you already have a return statement just a heads up

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am using the handler for everz checkbox onPress `      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          checkedHandler_2();
          // answerHandler();
        }}
      .....
      </TouchableOpacity>`

Comment: and then like this: 
`
  const checkedHandler_2 = () => {
    if (checked_2 == false) {
      setChecked_2(true);
      setUserInput(userInput + props.box_2_Letter);
      answerHandler();
    } else {
      setChecked_2(false);
      setUserInput(userInput.replace(props.box_2_Letter, ""));
      answerHandler();
    }
  };
`

Comment: I updated the question with the code to make is easier to read...

Comment: What is the value that is jumping to true ?

Comment: Its "userInput" in the checkbox component..

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in the reducer. You are returning the result of the variable assignment (`state = true/false`) which is always going to return `true` when everything is working as it should.

Since you are replacing the state entirely, just return the value and ignore the old variable i.e.

```
case `ANSWER_TRUE`:
  return true;
case `ANSWER_FALSE`:
  return false;
default:
  return state;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - it still "jumps" to true in the end everytime :-(

Comment: @Twos22 are you using React hooks by any chance?

Comment: I do - both in the checkbox component and the main screen where the checkbox component is used.

Comment: @Twos22 can you post those two components in full? Also, can you confirm that your Redux state is now correct based on the changes above? That will tell us that it's a UI problem and not a store problem.

Comment: thank you again for your reply. I updated the questions with the full code of the component and the screen I use the component in. The redux state still "automatically" switches/jumps from true to false and true again

Comment: I'm guessing your `makeAnswerStateFalseAgainHandler` is running everytime your Redux store changes as it's forcing the component to re-render. I presume you've got some form of Redux logger installed? Should help clarify that, not sure if there's the Redux Dev Tools equivalent for Native, either way you should be able to install a simple logger middleware like [redux-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger)

Comment: Dear James and dear @kodamace Thank you guys for the help - I wasn't able to solve this mess but I decieded to re-write the whole thing and work with props now :D I'll get back to redux when I have the time to actually dive deep in :-)

Comment: @Twos22 absolutely nothing wrong with that, and in fact, if you were easily able to remove Redux then it's a good indicator that you probably didn't need it in the first place :) I would typically recommend starting with Redux Context first as a state management mechanism and only then moving to Redux when you find state management becomes very intertwined